# Cannot RDP from inside to dmz

Tags: rdp, cisco-asa

- I'm running an ASA 5505 with security plus
- I have internet access from the inside and dmz vlans
- I can Remote Desktop from inside to another machine on the inside
- I can ping inside machines and machines on the internet
- I'm using the ASDM to configure the router.

How do can I remote desktop to my DMZ?

Below is my config and the packet trace

```
Result of the command: "sh run"

: Saved
:
ASA Version 8.2(5) 
!
hostname evo-fw-ext
enable password *password* encrypted
passwd *password* encrypted
names
name 10.10.1.200 buildserver
name 192.168.1.2 evo-fw-int
name 10.10.1.100 webserver
name *myip* outside-buildserver
name *myip* outside-webserver
name 192.168.1.10 appserver
name 192.168.1.250 vpn-host-1
!
interface Ethernet0/0
 switchport access vlan 2
!
interface Ethernet0/1
!
interface Ethernet0/2
!
interface Ethernet0/3
!
interface Ethernet0/4
!
interface Ethernet0/5
!
interface Ethernet0/6
 switchport access vlan 5
!
interface Ethernet0/7
 switchport access vlan 5
!
interface Vlan1
 nameif inside
 security-level 100
 ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0 
!
interface Vlan2
 nameif outside
 security-level 0
 ip address 209.94.254.250 255.255.255.248 
!
interface Vlan5
 nameif dmz
 security-level 50
 ip address 10.10.1.1 255.255.255.0 
!
ftp mode passive
object-group service DM_INLINE_TCP_1 tcp
 port-object eq www
 port-object eq https
object-group service DM_INLINE_TCP_2 tcp
 port-object eq www
 port-object eq https
access-list inside_nat0_outbound extended permit ip any 192.168.1.248 255.255.255.248 
access-list outside_access_in extended permit tcp any host outside-webserver object-group DM_INLINE_TCP_1 
access-list outside_access_in extended permit tcp any host outside-buildserver object-group DM_INLINE_TCP_2 
pager lines 24
logging enable
logging asdm informational
mtu inside 1500
mtu outside 1500
mtu dmz 1500
ip local pool VPN1 vpn-host-1-192.168.1.255 mask 255.255.255.0
no failover
icmp unreachable rate-limit 1 burst-size 1
no asdm history enable
arp timeout 14400
global (outside) 1 interface
nat (inside) 0 access-list inside_nat0_outbound
nat (inside) 1 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0
nat (dmz) 1 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0
static (dmz,outside) tcp outside-webserver www webserver www netmask 255.255.255.255 
static (dmz,outside) tcp outside-buildserver www buildserver www netmask 255.255.255.255 
access-group outside_access_in in interface outside
route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 *gateway* 1
timeout xlate 3:00:00
timeout conn 1:00:00 half-closed 0:10:00 udp 0:02:00 icmp 0:00:02
timeout sunrpc 0:10:00 h323 0:05:00 h225 1:00:00 mgcp 0:05:00 mgcp-pat 0:05:00
timeout sip 0:30:00 sip_media 0:02:00 sip-invite 0:03:00 sip-disconnect 0:02:00
timeout sip-provisional-media 0:02:00 uauth 0:05:00 absolute
timeout tcp-proxy-reassembly 0:01:00
timeout floating-conn 0:00:00
dynamic-access-policy-record DfltAccessPolicy
http server enable
http 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 inside
no snmp-server location
no snmp-server contact
snmp-server enable traps snmp authentication linkup linkdown coldstart
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA esp-3des esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-AES-256-MD5 esp-aes-256 esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-DES-SHA esp-des esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-DES-MD5 esp-des esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-AES-192-MD5 esp-aes-192 esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-3DES-MD5 esp-3des esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-AES-256-SHA esp-aes-256 esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA esp-aes esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-AES-192-SHA esp-aes-192 esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-AES-128-MD5 esp-aes esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec security-association lifetime seconds 28800
crypto ipsec security-association lifetime kilobytes 4608000
crypto dynamic-map SYSTEM_DEFAULT_CRYPTO_MAP 65535 set pfs 
crypto dynamic-map SYSTEM_DEFAULT_CRYPTO_MAP 65535 set transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA ESP-AES-128-MD5 ESP-AES-192-SHA ESP-AES-192-MD5 ESP-AES-256-SHA ESP-AES-256-MD5 ESP-3DES-SHA ESP-3DES-MD5 ESP-DES-SHA ESP-DES-MD5
crypto map outside_map 65535 ipsec-isakmp dynamic SYSTEM_DEFAULT_CRYPTO_MAP
crypto map outside_map interface outside
crypto isakmp enable outside
crypto isakmp policy 10
 authentication pre-share
 encryption aes-256
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
telnet timeout 5
ssh timeout 5
console timeout 0
dhcpd auto_config outside
!
dhcpd address 192.168.1.5-192.168.1.254 inside
dhcpd dns 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 interface inside
dhcpd enable inside
!

threat-detection basic-threat
threat-detection statistics access-list
no threat-detection statistics tcp-intercept
webvpn
 anyconnect-essentials
group-policy colo internal
group-policy colo attributes
 dns-server value 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
 vpn-tunnel-protocol IPSec 
username un password pw encrypted privilege 0
username un attributes
 vpn-group-policy colo
tunnel-group colo type remote-access
tunnel-group colo general-attributes
 address-pool VPN1
 default-group-policy colo
tunnel-group colo ipsec-attributes
 pre-shared-key *****
!
class-map inspection_default
 match default-inspection-traffic
!
!
policy-map type inspect dns preset_dns_map
 parameters
  message-length maximum client auto
  message-length maximum 512
policy-map global_policy
 class inspection_default
  inspect dns preset_dns_map 
  inspect ftp 
  inspect h323 h225 
  inspect h323 ras 
  inspect rsh 
  inspect rtsp 
  inspect esmtp 
  inspect sqlnet 
  inspect skinny  
  inspect sunrpc 
  inspect xdmcp 
  inspect sip  
  inspect netbios 
  inspect tftp 
  inspect ip-options 
!
service-policy global_policy global
prompt hostname context 
no call-home reporting anonymous
Cryptochecksum:*checksum*
: end
```

packet trace

Result of the command: "packet-tracer input inside tcp 192.168.1.5 12345 10.10.1.100 3389 xml"

```
<Phase>
<id>1</id>
<type>ROUTE-LOOKUP</type>
<subtype>input</subtype>
<result>ALLOW</result>
<config>
</config>
<extra>
in   10.10.1.0       255.255.255.0   dmz
</extra>
</Phase>

<Phase>
<id>2</id>
<type>IP-OPTIONS</type>
<subtype></subtype>
<result>ALLOW</result>
<config>
</config>
<extra>
</extra>
</Phase>

<Phase>
<id>3</id>
<type>NAT</type>
<subtype></subtype>
<result>DROP</result>
<config>
nat (inside) 1 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0
  match ip inside any dmz any
    dynamic translation to pool 1 (No matching global)
    translate_hits = 15, untranslate_hits = 0
</config>
<extra>
</extra>
</Phase>

<result>
<input-interface>inside</input-interface>
<input-status>up</input-status>
<input-line-status>up</input-line-status>
<output-interface>dmz</output-interface>
<output-status>up</output-status>
<output-line-status>up</output-line-status>
<action>drop</action>
<drop-reason>(acl-drop) Flow is denied by configured rule</drop-reason>
</result>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no nat `global` for your traffic coming from 192.168.1.5 traversing from `inside` to the `dmz` IP 10.10.1.100.  Having `nat (inside) 1 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0` creates such an expectation.

Add the following to your `inside_nat0_outbound` ACL to allow 192.168.1.0/24 hosts to access 10.10.1.0/24 hosts w/o requiring NAT.

```
access-list inside_nat0_outbound extended permit ip 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 10.10.1.0 255.255.255.0
```

(Your `inside_nat0_outbound` ACL has me scratching my head a little bit. Why somebody would want the hosts 192.168.1.248 - 192.168.254 to egress to the Internet w/o NAT is a bit strange...)

Comment: I don't remember how that got added, tbh... I think it might be from my remote access IPSec VPN. What command would I issue if I got rid of that rule?

Comment: You can just "no" it out of the configuration.

Comment: Sorry, my question wasn't clear, I mean if i got rid of the ins9de_nat0_outbound, would the command you wrote in the answer change?

Comment: I wouldn't remove the entire `inside_nat0_outbound` ACL, because it's configured to do what you want in the `nat (inside) 0 ...` statement. I'd just `no` out the entry you don't need in the ACL (from the old IPSEC VPN).